# How to store height information as a float in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to store height information as a float in spring-data-elasticsearch. My data model looks like this

```
Height.java
    int feet, inches;

@Document(indexName = "users", shards = 1, versionType = VersionType.INTERNAL, createIndex = true)
public class User implements Persistable<String> {
    private Height height;
}
```

Comment: you mean to store 2 feet and 3 inches as 2.25?

Comment: Yes, got it resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FloatConverter seems to work

```
@WritingConverter
public enum ToFloatConverter implements Converter<Height, Float> {

    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public Float convert(Height height) {
        String heightStr = height.getFeet() + "." + height.getInches();
        return Float.parseFloat(heightStr);
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll need another for to convert from Float to Height when reading the documents back